# <eval>:4:4 Expected an operand but found const

Tags: javascript

и так, я делаю скрипт на js, мне нужно сделать while но с задержкой в 2секунды

```js
module = script.registerModule("AntiAFK",PLAYER);

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
  }

module.onEvent("enable",function(){
    while (true)
    {
        player.jump()
        if(player.isOnGround()){
            player.setX(player.getX()+1)
        }
        sleep(2000);
    }
        
})
```

при выполнении пишет это [image: цук]

Comment: где запускается этот скрипт?

Comment: Novoline https://novoline.wft @Grundy

Comment: где ты брал пример этого скрипта?

Comment: https://novoline.gitbook.io/novoscript/ @Grundy

Comment: а функция `sleep`?

Comment: Откуда вообще идея добавить бесконечный цикл появилась?

Comment: делаю AntiAFK чтобы он выполнял однии теже действия всегда, когда включён скрипт

Comment: судя по всему тебе нужно [что-то вроде таймера](https://novoline.gitbook.io/novoscript/api/utilities/timer-utility), но можно ли его использовать внутри обработчиков событий из документации непонятно

Comment: Так как в вопросе речь идет не про javascript, стоит об этом явно указывать, давая ссылки на документацию.

Comment: @Grundy я кидал выку - novoline.gitbook.io/novoscript

Comment: Это нужно добавлять непосредственно в вопрос, в комментариях не все можно найти.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вместо `let` и `const` использовать `var`

Comment: не работает( нету ошибки, но просто виснет

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/682684)

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, на самом деле это все-таки ответ, и проблема в том числе и в `let` и `const`

Comment: @DaemonHK я не оставлял замечания и не просил уточнений. Я предложил своё решение и не понимаю, почему это должно быть комментарием. Если это полностью не решает все ошибки у автора, которые возникли уже после внесения изменений из моего ответа – это уже другая проблема для еще одного вопроса. Или тема для раскручивания текущего далее в комментариях.

Comment: @AleksandrBelous изучите, что такое очередь проверок.